# View/Dump APC contents?

Tags: php, apc

I'm trying to view what's stored in my server's APC, is there a way to do this?  I've seen solutions that appear to dump the contents into files but I'd rather just print it out on screen (it's a small amount of data stored).  I'd even accept a solution that let me view it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script delivered with APC called `apc.php`. Open this file in a browser to get a lot of useful information. One of it's features is showing the currently cached contents.

Alternatively you might want to look at the [`apc_cache_info`](http://php.net/apc_cache_info) function.

Comment: that does seem helpful, but I still can't see variables - I have about 10 or so arrays stored in it now and all I see is my application's php files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short ad-hoc solution using `apc_cache_info()` (mentioned by NikiC) :

```
$cacheInfo = apc_cache_info();
foreach($cacheInfo['cache_list'] as $cacheItem)
    echo print_r(apc_fetch($cacheItem['info']), true);
```